# atop - next page in process list, same processes

Tags: linux, debian, top

I use [atop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop) logs to examine state of my server. I am confused *next page* option:

```
    ^F  - show next page in the process-list (forward)
```

`atop` shows me a process list as follows:

```
21559 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21565 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21533 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21534 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21535 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21538 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
21541 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
21544 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
```

I press `^F` to see next processes and I get

```
21535 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - S   0% python2.7
21538 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
21541 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
21544 ... 2013/03/13 12:59:52   active    active  --   - Z   0% python2.7
```

where all four processes were in the previous page. So, what exactly do I change when I press `^F`?

**Edit**

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)

Comment: Please include your Operating System. Pressing Ctrl+F in my debian box shows me the next page of processes. Could this be because of `atop` updating the displayed page? Perhaps processes on the first page are then moved to the second and that is why you see them.

Comment: I run atop with archived logs, so it does not update the displayed page (if this is what you ment)

Comment: If you are not running atop in interactive mode, what exactly do you expect `^F` to do? It sounds like you are using `less` or `more` to see the files, what you described is the typical behavior of both programs, `^F` will show the next page and the last few lines of the previous one.

Comment: No, I run in an interactive mode. What I expect is that on the 1st page I have, let say, 10 processes, on 2nd page I have next 10 processes, on 3rd I have 4 processes and nothing more. What I get is that on each page I have some set of processes that I saw on other pages, what makes little sense for me